# How to get a backref on Association Object - ie user.follows() and user.followers()

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to create an association object `UserRelationship` which defines a 'follow' relationship between `User` and `User`.

```
class UserRelationship(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    follows_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    follower_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    follows = db.relationship("User", foreign_keys=[follows_id])
    follower = db.relationship("User", foreign_keys=[follower_id])
    bank = db.Column(db.Float)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.follower.username} follows {self.follows.username} with {self.bank}'



class User(UserMixin, db.Model):

    follows = db.relationship('UserRelationship',
                              primaryjoin=(UserRelationship.follower_id == id),
                              backref=db.backref('followers'),
                              lazy='dynamic')

    def follow(self, user, bank):
        if not self.is_following(user):
            new_follow = UserRelationship(bank=bank)
            new_follow.follows = user
            self.follows.append(new_follow)
            db.session.commit()
            return new_follow

    def unfollow(self, user):
        if self.is_following(user):
            relationship = self.follows.filter(UserRelationship.follows == user).first()
            db.session.delete(relationship)
            db.session.commit()
            return self.follows.all()

    def is_following(self, user):
        return self.follows.filter(
            UserRelationship.follows == user).count() > 0
```

This produces expected results in the shell:

```
joe=User(username='joe')
paul=User(username='paul')
phil=User(username='phil')

phil.follow(joe,bank=123)
[phil follows joe with 123]
```

So when I user User.follows I get taken to a UserRelationship object, which I can query to get all the people THAT user follows. I get that. What I can't understand is how I can get User.followers to work. What I'd like is a query (or list) or User.followers. The backref command doesn't work = typing 'phil.followers' into console produces

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'followers'
```

I could write a function perhaps? But I'm not entirely sure what I'd write to query the database to get a list of Users who all follow a particular user.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out - it was actually pretty simple:

```
    def followers(self):
        return UserRelationship.query.filter_by(follows=self).all()
```